# Ubercart email notification to store owner when order submitted

Tags: 6, ubercart, rules, emails, notifications

I am new to Ubercart (we are installing and configuring on a Drupal 6 site) and have all of the store built out. I am attempting to set up a notification email to the store owner when an order is placed. I would think this is a built in configuration for ubercart... however for the life of me I can't find it.

Is there an Ubercart extension module which does this? Or should I configure this through Rules? I know there must be an existing and proven method for this in Ubercart somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "Conditional Actions" to achieve this.

Its available under Store Administration / Conditional Actions.
I believe there is a preconfigured conditional action for your request in Ubercart. Maybe you just need to enable it.

If not just create your own.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is actually what I ended up doing yesterday. I added a predicate via Conditional actions so whenever a customer completes checkout, an email notification is sent. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Also, take a look at the [UC Rules](http://drupal.org/project/uc_rules) module for Drupal 6.